# Removed the function of one of my mouse buttons by trying to change it

Tags: 14.04, mouse, button

I'm fairly new to Ubuntu. I'm using a mouse with two extra thumb buttons and I figured it would be handy to use them for volume control.

After googling around a bit I ended here: [Configuring mouse buttons to switch between apps?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/475287/configuring-mouse-buttons-to-switch-between-apps)
Decided to try it out (first with the example for switching apps to see if that worked).

So I wrote
        "xdotool key alt+Tab"
        b:9 + Release
in a file called .xbindkeysrc

I ran xbindkeys -v -n in the terminal, which seemed to work, however the mouse button did nothing. Upon closing and running again, I now got a warning too stating that there is some other program controlling the mouse buttons.

Upon using the command xev, which normally shows the number of the mouse button upon clicking in a white square, the ninth button didn't show 'button 9', instead it gave 'mode NotifyGrab, detail NotifyVirtual'

Any advice on how I can make it work the way I need to? Thanks a lot!

Comment: One useful trick when playing with keyboard and mouse remappings is that if you unplug the USB device and replug it again the settings are reset and you can start over.

Comment: It didn't work, stays as before.