# How to remap (recognize?) Corsair M55 left-handed buttons?

Tags: mouse, xinput

I am left-handed and share certain devices with my right-handed SO. I bought the Corsair M55 which seems adequate as a middle-tier shareable device given its symmetric design and the two (four) "thumb-buttons" for both left-handed and right-handed configurations.

However a `xinput --test <id>` shows that:

- Buttons 1-2-3 are standard (I plan to remap 1 and 3 for left-handed usage in my account).
- Buttons 4-5 are wheel buttons.
- Right-handed thumb buttons (those that are physically on the left side of the mouse) are 8 and 9.
- Left-handed thumb buttons (physically on the right side of the mouse) don't trigger anything.

How can I use those buttons? Why are they not triggering any xinput event? Have I missed any step?

Comment: Have you tried these possible solutions? https://askubuntu.com/questions/52139/how-do-i-configure-a-mouse-thumb-button

Comment: @darth_epoxy That link --and other instructions I found-- assume that the buttons are being recognized. Both `xinput` and `xev` fail to react to the two buttons, so those solutions are no use to my problem AFAICT.

Comment: It would seem you need specific HID for that hardware. If you are determined, give this a go https://github.com/ckb-next/ckb-next

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without drivers only one side of the thumb buttons is active at the time.
You can switch sides by holding both thumb buttons for three seconds:

- To switch to left-handed mode press both buttons on the left side
- To switch to left-handed mode press both buttons on the right side

Switching is signalized by blinking DPI LED, its persistent, and left-handed mode also swaps left-right mouse buttons